# Python: Display number as entered

Tags: python, casting

The entered number should be displayed as it was entered.
Example: enter 2 display 2 ; enter 3.2 display 3.2

You should be able to enter all numbers, negative, positive and decimal.

Current behaviour: Enter 2 display 2.0

```
zahl = float(input())

while not(zahl > 0 and zahl % 1 == 0):
  print('Ganze und positive Zahl eingeben: ' + str(zahl))
  zahl = float(input())

print('Ganze und positive Zahl eingeben: ' + str(zahl))
zahl = int(zahl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
zahl = float(input("Enter number: "))
if (zahl==int(zahl)):
    zahl=int(zahl)
print('Ganze und positive Zahl eingeben: ' + str(zahl))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original entered string to use in the message:

```
zahl_str = input()
zahl = float(zahl_str)
while not(zahl > 0 and zahl % 1 == 0):
  print('Ganze und positive Zahl eingeben: ' + zahl_str)
  zahl_str = input()
  zahl = float(zahl_str)

print('Ganze und positive Zahl eingeben: ' + zahl_str)
zahl = int(zahl)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
def typify(num):
    return int(num) if float(num) % 1 == 0 else float(num)

zahl = typify(input())

print(f'Ganze und positive Zahl eingeben: {zahl}')
```